# Set the value to the datepicker from a json

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying set the value to datepicker component under Sencha Touch from a store with the next code :

```
    setRDDConfigs: function () {
    var store = Ext.getStore('OrderOptions');
    var cartHeaderRDD = this.getHeaderRDD();

    Ext.each(store.getRange(), function (record) {
        var r = record.getData().rdd;
        var formatted = c.Helper.formatSAPdate2Str(r);
        console.log(r); // here  20140807  for example
        console.log(formatted); // here 07-08-2014
        cartHeaderRDD.setValue(new Date(r)); // NAN
        //cartHeaderRDD.setValue(formatted); //NAN
    });
},
```

In the view:

```
{
  xtype: 'CustomDatepicker',
  itemId: 'headerRDD',
  name: 'rdd',
  required: true,
  hidden: true
},
```

But it isn´t working properly..  what am i doing wrong??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
parsedDate = Ext.Date.parse(r, "Y-m-d");
cartHeaderRDD.setValue(parsedDate);
```

**Ext.Date.parse** takes a String as first input and the format as the secound.
The Result is a Date object if parsing was successfull or null if not.
Change the format according to your format in `r`.

For more informations see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-parse .

Comment: Glad to hear the code works for you, please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the date in setValue like this:

```
 cartHeaderRDD.setValue(new Date());
```

Comment: ok, It works for the current date but actually I need to get the value from a json and It isn´t the current date.  In the past with the current date was enough..

Comment: You can do that just by: cartHeaderRDD.setValue(new Date(r));

Comment: I tried this same example and now It´s working, but in the field is showing NAN, NAN, and so on..

Comment: Can you please give me an example of "r" that you are setting?

Comment: Ok. `cartHeaderRDD.setValue(new Date(formatted));` should do the work.

Comment: It is not working, I have added the current component datepicker in the view..   :-(

Comment: Weird. Tell me the output of `console.log(new Date(formatted));`.

Comment: Invalid Date is the output

Comment: Ok I suppose `formatted` is not in string.Convert it to string and try console.log(new Date(formatted.toString()));

Comment: It is not working..   value in the console is Invalid date ... and I am looking with typeOf formatted and It´s a string.